# Fit iframe content within div with percentage

Tags: html, css, iframe

So i'm trying to scale the content of an iframe to fit the width and height of an div. The div wrap has width 60% within another div with width 100%, NOT shown below.

I would like to get the iframe to take up the 60% with 100% inside. All heights are 100% for all divs. Please can someone help me!? Im using the
scale css property for each browser.

```
         <div class="iframe-wrap">
               <iframe class="iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
         </div>
```

Not sure, but some css3 like this?

```
        zoom: 0.75;
       -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -o-transform: scale(0.75);
       -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
       -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** [Codepen with video example](http://codepen.io/heavilyedited/pen/QbpmwW)

[See Codepen](http://codepen.io/heavilyedited/pen/aOJqqZ)

Here's an example, using a Google Map. You can add/remove/adjust the width and height for the parent div (`.iframe-wrapper`), but don't make any changes to `.iframe-wrapper iframe`.

`.iframe-wrapper { height: 0; padding-bottom: 30%; }` gives your parent div a responsive height that scales with the page. If you'd prefer a fixed height, just make sure to remove the `padding-bottom`. You can also remove the padding-bottom and set the height to 'auto,' depending on what you're trying to do.

```css
.iframe-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}
.iframe-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d56157.911598837636!2d-81.57591711561635!3d28.393010043266493!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88dd7ee634caa5f7%3A0xa71e391fd01cf1a0!2sWalt+Disney+World+Resort!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1433358634479" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that map does not shrink with the size of the iframe.

Comment: It does shrink; the controls along the sides of the map (zoom in/out, "Sign In") self-adjust accordingly. The map view itself does not shrink because Google Maps are designed to stay at the same zoom level regardless of screen size.

Maybe a different iframe example, like a video, would be more appropriate.

Comment: I solved it through mixing some % and the transform scale css values, im not sure its completely accurate. I believe we are discussing different aspects for this solution. I needed to get the content within the iframe to skrink. The maps solution does not do this, it just position the map accordingly. My target is to get a scale effect (full page, links etc) like a image being skrinked. Still thank you for the help.